# trying to add geofencing to an android app keep getting error

Tags: android, geofencing

I'm trying to add geofencing in an android application but I keep getting and error at the last step of adding the list of geofences to the map. the application has the required permissions and the list is populated.

this is the code i have:

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void addGeofences() {
        Log.d(TAG, "addGeofences: ");
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions();
            return;
        }
        mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: geofenccess added!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: failed to add geofences! : " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }


private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getGeofencingRequest()");
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();

        // The INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER flag indicates that geofencing service should trigger a
        // GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER notification when the geofence is added and if the device
        // is already inside that geofence.
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);

        // Add the geofences to be monitored by geofencing service.
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);

        // Return a GeofencingRequest.
        return builder.build();
    }
 private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getGeofencePendingIntent: ");
        // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
        if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
            return mGeofencePendingIntent;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling
        // addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
        mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
```

this is the error I get:

```
2019-11-03 16:52:10.183 21204-21204/com.alainsaris.thisisit D/MAP_ACTIVITY: addGeoFencing: created on:(50.642081,3.0992754), for: node/6638170780
2019-11-03 16:52:10.184 21204-21204/com.alainsaris.thisisit D/MAP_ACTIVITY: addGeoFencing: created on:(50.6521071,2.9742848), for: node/6659546245
2019-11-03 16:52:10.185 21204-21204/com.alainsaris.thisisit D/MAP_ACTIVITY: getGeofencingRequest()
2019-11-03 16:52:10.187 21204-21204/com.alainsaris.thisisit D/MAP_ACTIVITY: getGeofencePendingIntent: 
2019-11-03 16:52:10.595 21204-21204/com.alainsaris.thisisit D/MAP_ACTIVITY: onFailure: failed to add geofences! : 13:
```

I can't find what does that error mean or what causes it. this is the part where the list is populated and geofences should be created after putting markers in the map.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void addGeoFencing() {
        Log.d(TAG, "addGeoFencing: ");
        JSONObject featuresObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject stationObject = new JSONObject();
        InputStream XmlFileInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lille_stations); // getting XML
        String stationsObjectString = readTextFile(XmlFileInputStream);
        try {
            featuresObject = new JSONObject(stationsObjectString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONArray featuresArray = null;
        try {
            featuresArray = new JSONArray(featuresObject.get("features").toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String stationName = "station name";
        Double latitude = 0.0;
        Double longitude = 0.0;
        LatLng latLng;
        for (int i = 0; i < featuresArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                stationObject = (JSONObject) featuresArray.get(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                //get the station's name
                stationName = (String) stationObject.getJSONObject("properties").get("name");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                //get the station's coordinates
                JSONArray coordinatesArray;
                coordinatesArray = new JSONArray(stationObject.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONArray("coordinates").toString());
                latitude = (Double) coordinatesArray.get(1);
                longitude = (Double) coordinatesArray.get(0);

                //add the marker
                latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(stationName));

                //add the geofence to the geofence list
                mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                        // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                        // geofence.
//                        .setRequestId(stationObject.getJSONObject("properties").getString("@id"))
                        .setRequestId("a test")
                        // Set the circular region of this geofence.
                        .setCircularRegion(
                                latitude,
                                longitude,
                                100)

                        // Set the expiration duration of the geofence. This geofence gets automatically
                        // removed after this period of time.
                        .setExpirationDuration(3000)

                        // Set the transition types of interest. Alerts are only generated for these
                        // transition. We track entry and exit transitions in this sample.
                        .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                                Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)

                        // Create the geofence.
                        .build());
                Log.d(TAG, "addGeoFencing: created on:(" + latitude + "," + longitude + "), for: " + stationObject.getJSONObject("properties").getString("@id"));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        //add the geofences to the geofencing client from the mGeofencesList
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions();
            return;
        }
        mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: geofenccess added!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: failed to add geofences! : " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
```

the app gets the names and the latlng from a geojson in R.raw

Comment: for what it's worth, error 13 is "The operation failed with no more detailed information." see https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html and https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofenceStatusCodes.html

Comment: thanks man, turns out there is a problem with the android emulator, when I tried using my phone it worked. I still don't know how to fix it to work in the emulator though.